# what does "denied: Account disabled." mean when pushing image to gcloud in my deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to deploy my meteor application to gcloud. The deployment's been working pretty well for the past few months. Have successfully deployed 50+ versions. But when I try to deploy the latest version this time I ran into a strange error in the last stage when it comes to pushing the image to gcloud:

```
Successfully built b052f5c9ce51
Successfully tagged asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042:latest
PUSH
Pushing asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042:latest
The push refers to a repository [asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042]
3c395dc9491c: Preparing
d6326beb91f5: Preparing
1d66e1f12b20: Preparing
333e94736e35: Preparing
e0ef2f61d575: Preparing
e1ded7a4e5ed: Preparing
3c9e8a0fcc06: Preparing
257da68b6c7d: Preparing
b42d9538f28c: Preparing
a4c6a82953f0: Preparing
5a2c5095cca1: Preparing
e1ded7a4e5ed: Waiting
3c9e8a0fcc06: Waiting
257da68b6c7d: Waiting
b42d9538f28c: Waiting
a4c6a82953f0: Waiting
5a2c5095cca1: Waiting
denied: Account disabled.
Pushing asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042:latest
The push refers to a repository [asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042]
3c395dc9491c: Preparing
d6326beb91f5: Preparing
1d66e1f12b20: Preparing
3c395dc9491c: Waiting
d6326beb91f5: Waiting
333e94736e35: Preparing
e0ef2f61d575: Preparing
e1ded7a4e5ed: Preparing
e1ded7a4e5ed: Waiting
1d66e1f12b20: Waiting
333e94736e35: Waiting
e0ef2f61d575: Waiting
3c9e8a0fcc06: Preparing
3c9e8a0fcc06: Waiting
e1ded7a4e5ed: Waiting
257da68b6c7d: Preparing
b42d9538f28c: Preparing
a4c6a82953f0: Preparing
a4c6a82953f0: Waiting
3c9e8a0fcc06: Waiting
257da68b6c7d: Waiting
b42d9538f28c: Waiting
5a2c5095cca1: Preparing
a4c6a82953f0: Waiting
5a2c5095cca1: Waiting
denied: Account disabled.
...
Pushing asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042:latest
denied: Account disabled.
ERROR: failed to push because we ran out of retries.
ERROR
ERROR: error pushing image "asia.gcr.io/ld-eq-163912/appengine/default.20171029t235042:latest": exit status 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I kept getting `denied: Account disabled.` and then it just kept retrying until `ERROR: failed to push because we ran out of retries.` shows up.

When I do `gcloud auth list` it shows that I'm logged into the right account.

What's going on here?

Comment: Any chance that you did something that violated the terms of service?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I have no idea. I didn't receive any email regarding that from gcloud at all

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Is there a way I can look this up in the gcloud panel? Thanks!

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I was just looking around when I saw that for some reason there is no longer a billing account associated with my gcloud. Can that be where the problem is?

Comment: That'd do it. And it's easier to recover from than a ToS violation.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Ah I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dave W. Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62288/dave-w-smith) has suggested, this is likely [a result of something along the line of a ToS violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002503/what-does-denied-account-disabled-mean-when-pushing-image-to-gcloud-in-my-de?noredirect=1#comment80957424_47002503).

Further introspection into the activity log page (i.e. of the URL `https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?project=<project_id>`) on the Google Cloud Platform for my project suggested that it is a 403 error where the project

> *"cannot accept requests to X while in an inactive billing state."*

But there is no indications regarding this inactive billing state in anywhere else on the Google Cloud Platform. On the Billing page it only informs me that "no billing account has been linked to the project" and nothing about this "inactive  billing state".

Apparently a former collaborator had removed the only billing account linked to the project (which he has full ownership of, well it's his credit card) without notifying anyone in the current team. And funny enough even GCloud didn't notify me of such an activity that will result in such an annoyingly ambiguous error in deployment.

I hope GCloud can at least provide something like a pointer for errors like this in the terminal other than just a general statement saying "denied: Account disabled". So much time could have been saved if GCloud informs me that more info can be found in the GCP's activity logs so that I don't have to play this detective game.

Once again thank you Dave for giving me the right pointer helping getting me unstuck here.